# Laravel 5 allow console commands to run in maintenance mode

Tags: php, laravel-5, command

Using Laravel 5.2  to put the app in maintenance mode using artisan:

```
artisan down
```

However console commands don't seem to work, and my queues have paused.

How to allow console commands and queues to run, but prevent any users from logging in?

Use case: cron job calls artisan command which polls a directory on a server. When it finds a semaphore it queues the related files for processing. There are times when I just want to stop any users from using the gui, but still allow the queues to get processed.

1. From *the command line* put the app in a state where http/s routes are disabled, but console commands and queues can still run.
2. still have the ability to run artisan down when I want to, say, restore a backup. In this case, it is understood that console commands will be blocked.

These SO answers were helpful, but not exactly what is needed.

[[Laravel FrozenNode Administrator run in maintenance mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17756785/laravel-frozennode-administrator-run-in-maintenance-mode][1])

[[Laravel 4 bypass maintenance mode for a route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24574052/laravel-4-bypass-maintenance-mode-for-a-route][2])

Comment: Did you find a solution? I've the same problem: I need to go into maintenance mode BUT to allow artisan command  (and Queue !) to go on working ....

Comment: Sadly, no. as a workaround I'm manually commenting the routes file.

Comment: I'm actually on Laravel 5.4 and when app is down, artisan can run without any problems. Probably it's changed more or less recently.